# js (v8) rest params and gc

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, v8

does rest params allocate array

```js
function foo(a, b, ...rest) {
/*...*/
}
```

in example above its obvoius that array created, but what about this case

```js
function foo(...rest) {
/*...*/
}
```

there `rest` technicly the same as `arguments`

```js
function foo() {
   console.log.apply(null, arguments)
}
```

so, if i want avoid generate garbage could i prefer to use `arguments` or not ?
also, does `arguments` exists always or only when keyword used in function scope?
(if always, i assume thet using it is probably better, if not, is there any difference betwin rest and `arguments`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `rest` technicly the same as `arguments`

Not really. Rest parameters create a proper array, while the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) famously [is not an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31163324/1048572) but [needs to be converted to one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/960866/1048572). And in sloppy mode, [it behaves even weirder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38275455/1048572), *aliasing* the variables that are declared as parameters.

> Does `arguments` exists always or only when keyword used in function scope?

It is created only when any code in the function refers to it - this is a relatively trivial optimisation with big impact, not having to allocate a new object for every single function call. And in fact, this optimisation goes even further in V8, sometimes not even instantiating the object even code refers to it, see [What's the deal with optimising arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29198195/1048572) and [*Crankshaft vs arguments object* by Vyacheslav Egorov](https://mrale.ph/blog/2015/11/02/crankshaft-vs-arguments-object.html) for details.

> Is there any difference, should i prefer to use `arguments`?

In modern code, you should generally prefer rest parameters. They are cleaner (less weird behavior), more declarative (easier to understand), and are actual arrays (so that you can use the usual array methods). They are the idiomatic choice.